# How to delete a jsPlumb connections in a specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm bit new to jsPlumb. I want to delete jsPlumb connections (all connections) in a given div.

When I use jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection(); all the connection in the whole page get deleted. I want to delete connections just in a given div.

Please help me!

Edited>>

Btw if you have got wrong idea; in my page there are some divs. Within those divs, there are some more divs among which there are jsPlumb connections. What I want is to delete connections among inner divs in a given outer div.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use **detachAllConnections** method from jsPlumb API :

```
jsPlumb.detachAllConnections(div_id);
```

//here div_id is id of your specified div

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not working for me.

Comment: if you want to remove inner connections then pass parent div id of all those connections.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all connections, use

`detachEveryConnection()`

[Documentation](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/removing.html)

Make sure to invoke it on the correct instance of jsPlumb.

To be sure, that you're invoking the right instance, try using `instance.getAllConnections()` to see if connections to that instance exists or not.

## **Update**

To detach every connection associated with a particular element, use

```
detachAllConnections(id_of_the_element);
```